# 400 Bad Request when calling wcf webservice. Used to work - now fails

Tags: wcf, request, webservice-client

I am stumped.  This worked this morning and now I get a 400 Bad Request error.  I haven't changed anything in the web service itself nor have I changed anything in the tiny app I use to test my web service.  The only thing that comes to mind is that I saw a balloon pop up earlier indicating there were updates for VisualStudio 2012.   I've been beating my head against the wall for hours now and making no progress.  I've gone so far as to shut down VS and restart and when that didn't work I even rebooted.  I then unschelved code I had shelved at the end of last week and THAT CODE also now gets a 400 Bad Request error when the test application tries to call the web service.  I can get a wsdl from the webservice so it is running and responding.  Anyway, here is the code my test app uses to connect to the web service.  Do you guys see anything wrong?  Do you have any ideas?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sr = new ServiceReference1.AcordWebService();

        string outXML = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\..\WCFTester\Order.xml");

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sr.Url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] byteArray = GetBytes(outXML);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            respXML.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which specific VS update did you install?

Comment: Is there a double-face palm icon?  To answer your question, I didn't actively install the update but it appears when I rebooted it must have automatically installed.  However, the update has nothing to do with the problem.  It has everything to do with the contents of the Order.xml file.  I had accidentally stripped the soap headers from the file at some point.